# ruby memory analyzer

Tags: ruby, memory, analysis

I just want to know how system memory(RAM) gets affected by a ruby code.

Lets take for example a ruby code given below:

```
i = 0
while i < 100
  puts i = i +1
end
```

how much memory will it consume when this bit of code is ran. Can we measure these things.

Are there any tools for analyzing what's going in memory when this code is ran?

Thanks

Comment: http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/